# Converting Date in Extjs

Tags: date, extjs

I have a Date string of following format:

`'31-OCT-2013'`

How do I convert this into Date of following format using Extjs 4:

`'08/31/2013'`

I am using IE8.

Answer (score 17):

If you have string "31-OCT-2013", you need to:

Convert it into date object

```
var myDate = Ext.Date.parse("31-OCT-2013", 'd-M-Y');
```

Format it to as you want

```
Ext.Date.format(myDate, 'm/d/Y');
```

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this:

If your day representation would be 2 digit with leading zero, then apply this

```
var date = Ext.Date.parse("31-OCT-2013", 'd-M-Y');
console.log(Ext.Date.format(date, 'm/d/Y'));
```

But if your day representation would be without a leading zero, then apply this

```
var date = Ext.Date.parse("31-OCT-2013", 'j-M-Y');
console.log(Ext.Date.format(date, 'm/d/Y'));
```

Check the docs for [Ext.Date](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Date)

Comment: Pretty sure you want Ext.Date.parse('31-OCT-2013', 'd-m-Y').  'd/m/y' is the output format, 'd-m-Y' is the input.

Also, it's hard to tell from the example, but if the day portion uses only a single digit for days 1-9, he should swap 'j' in for the 'd'.  

Right on for the output formatting though.